# How to convert int variable and append to const wchar_t*

Tags: c++, string

I need a final query like this:
      `const wchar_t *fin = L"UPDATE info SET status = 'closed' where age = '12'";`

If the function receives a value I want to append something like this:
    `const wchar_t *fin = L"UPDATE info SET status = 'closed' where age = " + convertedAge;`

Here is my update function code:

```
void updateDB(int passAge){
   std::wstring myString;
   convertedAge= std::to_wstring(passAge);
   const wchar_t* fin = L"UPDATE info SET status = 'closed' where age = " + convertedAge;
}
```

How to convert that integer variable in order append that one in `const wchar_t*`and act as a single query?

Comment: I prefer using bind functions to set the variables.

Comment: @AndreiDamian Interesting. Can you show me how?

Comment: Any database drivers should have bind functions for sql.  Example for sqlite: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html . That is, assuming that sql is actually going to be executed by a database. If not, then the accepted answer is best.

Comment: @AndreiDamian Actually, this query will be executed in the database. I just posted the string concat part.

Comment: @AndreiDamian I'm using MSSQL server.

Comment: Before you continue this practice, note that this style of building SQL queries leads to an exploit called [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). The proper solution is parameterized queries. Andrei's comment is not just good style bus safety-critical.

Comment: @MSalters Yes. That was a good idea but I don't know how to implement that. Can you give me an example for that? Should I use procedural queries? I only knew basic. I'll be happy to get some knowledge from you. :)

Comment: I'm not an expert on MSSQL and it does depend a bit on the exact SQL interface you're using, but StackOverflow, MSDN and other sites have plenty of information already - this is so essential that every DBA needs it.

Comment: @MSalters Ok. I'll research for that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ standard string class includes a `.c_str()` function just for such situations.

```
void updateDB(int passAge){
   std::wstring myString = L"UPDATE info SET status = 'closed' where age = '" 
                        + std::to_wstring(passAge) + L"'";
   const wchar_t* fin = convertedAge.c_str();
}
```

Comment: Just because you beat me in lines of code, I'll prefer your answer. :)

Comment: @JAMESBRYANB.Juventud It takes time to get used to the standard library. But once you do, it's your most fearsome weapon as a C++ developer! :)

Comment: Yesss, Newbie problems. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've finally solved it. I dont't know if this is the best way. Here is my code.

```
void updateDB(int passAge){

  //Convert age to string
   std::string q = "'";
   std::wstring w;
   std::wstring endStr (q.begin(), q.end());
    w = endStr;

   std::wstring close(L"UPDATE info SET status = 'closed' where age = '");
   close += std::to_wstring(passAge);
   close += (w);

   const wchar_t *finClose = close.c_str();

   std::wcout << finClose << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: This is a bit overkill, you could just do what you ask in a single line.

Comment: Yeah. I read a lot articles just for this one. I'm just new in C++ that's why my coding is like C style.